# Subclass an original .NET Class

Tags: vb.net

I rewrite my functions in manner to not use VisualBasic namespace any more.
For example like this:

```
Public Function _Between(ByVal _string As String, _
                         ByVal _firstchar As String, _
                         ByVal _secondchar As String) As String

    Dim retval As String = ""
    Dim first, second As Integer

    Try
        first = _string.IndexOf(_firstchar) + 1
        second = _string.IndexOf(_secondchar) - 1
        If first >= 0 And second >= 0 Then
            retval = _string.Substring(first, second)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Return retval
End Function
```

This is function for create a string from existed string between given characters 'first' and 'second' similar to Basic MID$ function.

Using of this function is classical, for example:

```
mynumber = CDbl(_Between(cbovalue, " ", "%"))
```

Question is:
Is here possible (and how) to subclass an original .NET's 'string' class so I can use such function on more "NET" way like this:

```
 mynumber = CDbl(cbovalue._Between(" ", "%"))
```

... and get member "_Between" in suggestion's list in VB.IDE?

Comment: Use an extension method.  Your use of Try/Catch is evil, don't do that.

Comment: One possibility would be to use [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx).

Comment: String's probably sealed, so an extension method is probably your only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That feature is called extension method: [Extension Methods (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx)

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module StringExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Function _Between(ByVal _string As String, _
                         ByVal _firstchar As String, _
                         ByVal _secondchar As String) As String

        Dim retval As String = ""
        Dim first, second As Integer

        Try
            first = _string.IndexOf(_firstchar) + 1
            second = _string.IndexOf(_secondchar) - 1
            If first >= 0 And second >= 0 Then
                retval = _string.Substring(first, second)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Return retval
    End Function

End Module
```

With that you'll be able to call the method as you've described it: from the first parameter type specifying only the rest of them:

```
cbovalue._Between(" ", "%")
```

Of course, `cbovalue` has to be `String` variable.

Comment: Thank's Marcin. My function is in one Public Module on which I Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices, but I get error message Type 'Extension' is not defined.

Comment: I also try <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> without wanted result. Could be true that my NET2.0 don't support extensions?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't. Extension methods were introduced in .NET 3.5