# Minimal requirement for Try/Catch block

Tags: vb.net

I posted a code example in [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335866/subclass-an-original-net-class) and here is critical part:

```
Try
    first = _string.IndexOf(_firstchar) + 1
    second = _string.IndexOf(_secondchar)
    If first >= 1 And second >= 0 Then
        retval = _string.Substring(first, second - first)
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

One of experienced VB users say that such usage of Try/Catch is "evil".

Why is such usage "evil" and what is minimally enough to get program to continue when we don't want to bother with error?

Comment: There are many levels of evil here.  But the worst one is that it got you to ignore the bug in your code.  You probably actually found the bug but didn't fix it.

Comment: Well, I test function (something) ant it work's well on "different situations". Don't see a bug?

Comment: Between("abca", "b", "a").  Kaboom.

Comment: Khm :(, you re' right, as always. But this function is designed for my internal purposes where first and second chars will be like <> or [] or something what can't easy happen accidentally with text. Tim Schmelter fixes "abca" situation by second searching from place AFTER first character is finded. Anyway, thanks for testing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An empty `Catch` block is evil since it can hide exceptions that you should handle. The `Try-Catch` is redundant here, you should use the overload with a start index for the second :

```
first = _string.IndexOf(_firstchar)      
If first >= 0 Then
    first += 1
    second = _string.IndexOf(_secondchar, first)
    If second >= 0 Then
        retval = _string.Substring(first, second - first)
    End If
End If
```

Note that you should use `AndAlso` instead of `And`.

Comment: Hello Tim. But this code havent any error checking and on weird input program can crash here. Why to use AndAlso instead of And and did this apply for all And operators in whole program or just this example?

Comment: @user973238: It has no `Try-Catch` because it is safe. It's not possible that an exception is raised due to invalid data. If you use `And` both sides are evaluated eve if the first already returned false. That can cause an exception, e.g.: `If nullVariable IsNot Nothing And nullVariable.Property=1`

Comment: I tested your code a bit and can't successfully produce an error with input string so it seem really safe. Thanks for good idea.

Comment: One final note: you should avoid empty catch blocks because they hide exceptions that you should handle.  Handle means logging or - more important - fixing the reason of the exception if possible.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that is considered bad practice is because the exception you are catching there is not really handled in any way so it goes unnoticed. That in turn can cause other problems further down the program flow and those would be heard to gave back to the root cause, or even if traced, fixing them might be complicated by the previous decision to mask the error condition.

That said, there may be rare circumstances where it would be appropriate to *swallow* an exception like that. But if you do make that decision make sure to document the fact and state the reason you decided to ignore the error at that point.

For instance, it might be appropriate to ignore an exception that is triggered by a logging function. Since the purpose of the logger is to log the error, if for some reason the logging fails, there is probably not much else to do with that exception..

Comment: Well said. And *if* you decide the ignore an error, you should only ignore *one specific, well-defined error* rather than *all possible errors*.

Comment: Yes, in almost all cases, that goes without saying!

Comment: Ok, thanx Miky, then this is functional and not technical disadvantage of ignoring errors.